# How do I report a problem to for a pre-built package?

Tags: package-management

I recently installed the "timeline" app on my Ubuntu 20.xx system.

It mostly works but produces horrible failures when and if it is used to try to export to an SVG file.

This problem is apparently due to the absence, on my Ubuntu 20,xx system, of a particular Python package called wxPython.

I have tried to get that package installed, but my attempts to install wxPython are failing.

Simple question:  How can I find the name and email address of whoever it is who is the current maintainer of the wxPython package for Linux?  I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.xx system, so I can't provide specifics for a package given I don't know what release & provide how I'd follow the details, but Ubuntu 20.04 is the 2020-April release which is now very old (*five releases ago today, will be six releases ago later in the week*) so most package maintainers will require it to be re-tested on the latest release anyway, as it's easiest to fix issues on the *development* release and backport where necessary.  Ubuntu's wiki is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: How did you install the timeline app?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install python3-wxgtk4.0`